# Update google maps rectangles on zoom

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to make the rectangles in this script 
     http://jsfiddle.net/uLd7H/ 
to update on each zoom level.

I'm trying to let each rectangle appear only on the selected zoom level, and disappear when the level is changed.

For some reason it keeps drawing them over and over.

```
 function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30);
   var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: myLatLng
   };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
     var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
     map.setCenter(myLatLng);
if (zoomLevel>=1 && zoomLevel<=5) { 

   var r1 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
     strokeColor: '#FF0000',
     strokeOpacity: 0.8,
     strokeWeight: 2,
     fillColor: '#FF0000',
     fillOpacity: 0.35,
     map: map,
     bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
       new google.maps.LatLng(30, 29),
       new google.maps.LatLng(29, 30))
   });

 } else if (zoomLevel>5 && zoomLevel<=10) {

   var r2 = new google.maps.Rectangle({
     strokeColor: '#FFF000',
     strokeOpacity: 0.8,
     strokeWeight: 2,
     fillColor: '#FFF000',
     fillOpacity: 0.35,
          map: map,
          bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
       new google.maps.LatLng(29, 28),
       new google.maps.LatLng(28, 29))
   });
 }

   });
 }

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
```

Comment: Remember that the minor value is the minor zoom. While greater the value, greater the zoom.

Comment: Your error is that after show the rectangle, when you recede you are not cleaning them. You must remove them after do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create rectangles outside of event listener without map set so they are not visible. And on zoom change set map property:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    console.log(zoomLevel);
    map.setCenter(myLatLng);

    if (zoomLevel>=1 && zoomLevel<=5) { 
        r1.setMap(map);
        r2.setMap(null);
    } else if (zoomLevel>5 && zoomLevel<=10) {
        r1.setMap(null);
        r2.setMap(map);
    } else {
      r1.setMap(null);
      r2.setMap(null);
    }
});
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qojex/1/edit);